# Why is the damping RC used in these accelerometers?

Tags: transducer

What is the damping capacitor resistor couple used for at force balance accelerometers?:

[image]

Can you explain what happens as a malfunction if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Low pass filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R-C network functions as a low-pass filter that reduces the high-frequency noise (both mechanical and electrical) in the output signal. This noise, if not attenuated, would create aliasing issues if you're gioing to sample the data.